# ZendFramework .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess to rewrite my domain.com/ to domain.com/public/

```
# Rewrite rules for Zend Framework 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works fine but my logs report me that some bots try to access the file robots.txt and it doesn't exists.

If I access the url: http://domain.com/robots.txt doesn't work

but if I access the full url, it works http://domain.com/public/robots.txt

What I am doing wrong in the .htaccess?

Comment: Why exactly are you doing this? Nothing but whats in `public` should EVER be inside the DOCUMENT_ROOT. If you have a single Zend app that needs to be integrated into a larger existing site infrastructure then only put what should be in `public` in that structure and change the configuration to run as you have it set up.

Comment: I doing it because I have shared hosting and I can't put zendframework application one level down due open_basedir restriction.

Comment: Then you need to switch hosts. Only having access to the DOCUMENT_ROOT is not an acceptable situation in this day and age.

Comment: @rafael - add your extra info to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solved my issue

```
# Rewrite rules for Zend Framework 
RewriteEngine on 
Redirect permanent /robots.txt /public/robots.txt
Redirect permanent /favicon.ico /public/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this post.

http://www.alberton.info/zend_framework_mod_rewrite_shared_hosting.html

However, as advised, I recommend you to move to another host so your documentRoot points to your public folder.

Comment: It has the same effect as my old code. I would keep getting the error: Message: Invalid controller specified (robots.txt)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered your own question.
Move robots.txt into the same directory as your .htaccess file.

Also, you should think about moving your application/library folders up one level to keep them from direct public access.

Comment: Moving robots.txt one level down doesn't work, htaccess always rewrite to /public